# How can I make a dynamic JTabbedPane?

Tags: java

I want to do dynamic JTabbedPane, for example:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif");
JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("Panel #1");
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", icon, panel1,"Does nothing");
```

I can dynamically adding tabs to tabbedpane container. But problem is how can I design panels that I want to add tabbedpane. It's too hard to make from code behind. I can only add a label that's it. Is there any way to Design my panel then add it Jtabbedpane from code behind?

Comment: What tool are you going to use to design your panels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using some sort of swing GUI designer then create a class (design the gui) for the panel that you want to add to the tabbed pane, and then to dynamicaly add that panel to the tabbed pane just go
 `tabbedpane.addTab("Something",null,new MyPredesignedPanel(),"Something");`

Answer (score 2):

Why is it more difficult than dynamically adding tabs? Are you perhaps not using the right sort of LayoutManager? Generally, if you choose a good layout manager configuring panels will be much easier. I use the JGoodies Forms, and I heard good things about MigLayout.

Comment: +1 for MiGLayout - if you are still using JGoodies Forms, I definitely recommend that you try MiG out...